# Django & AJAX search view giving me KeyError

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-class-based-views

I'm adding an AJAX search feature to my Django blog application.

Here is my code:

**search_form.html**

```
<form id="search-form" method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="search-results">
    {% include "post_list.html" %}    //html file which simply views all the requested posts
</div>
```

**search.js**

```
function search_submit() {
    var query = $("#id_query").val();

    $("#search-results").load(
        "/search/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(query)
    );

    return false;
}
```

**views.py**

```
class PostSearch(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'search_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():              
            return self.render_to_response('post_list.html', self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.template_name, self.get_context_data(**kwargs))

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(TitleSearchMixin, self).get_queryset()

        q = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if q:
            return queryset.filter(question_title__icontains=q)
```

So basically, my QuestionSearch view just returns a "post_list.html" which is a template for viewing multiple posts for an AJAX request, while returning the whole "search_form.html" when it is a normal request. For some reason, this is giving me the error:

**ERROR:**

```
KeyError at /search/
u'object_list'
```

Since I am stuck, I have 2 questions..

(1) Why is this error occurring?

(2) Is my implementation of the search feature even done in the right way..? I've been reading about RESTf API design, yet I'm not sure whether mine is "RESTful" or not :((

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

could check post_list.html if you are iterating post_list variable or object_list?

if you are iterating (Looping) object_list change it to post_list or remove context_object_name = 'post_list' in class PostSearch(ListView):

Q2, what you are doing is a normal ajax, restful API requires serialization and CRUD operation 
for example GET to read
POST/PUT Insert/Update
Delete to delete

etc..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But if you look at my code, I already put  context_object_name = 'post_list' in the beginning, yet its giving me the KeyError....